# Lots of setTimeout() - how to srink?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a animation of a 3d cube using javascript. I've made the methods it needed.Like turning it.But to animate them I added setTimeout() function at a 2000 interval.

***Opps!Here is lots of setTimeout functions!***

Is there any way that I can creat a method to run the next code simply...???
Like this one!!!

**$(".cube .box").turn("right").wait(2000).turn("back").wait(300).turn("left")**

Simple but effective!!!
:-)

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $(".cube .box").turn("right");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".cube .box").turn("back");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".cube .box").turn("left");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".cube .box").turn("top");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".cube .box").turn("bottom");
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $(".cube .box").turn("front");
                        }, 2000);
                    }, 2000);
                }, 2000);
            }, 2000);
        }, 2000);
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Just use `delay` instead of `wait` and you are done...

Comment: What exactly is `turn`? It is not a jQuery function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const directions = ["right", "back", "left", "top", "bottom", "front"]

 function turn(i = 0){
   if(i >= directions.length) return;
   $(".cube .box").turn(directions[i]);
   setTimeout(turn, 2000, i + 1);
 }

 //Start
 setTimeout(turn, 2000);
```

Just use an indirect recursive function to iterate over all turns.

---

Or using jquerys `delay`

```
$(".cube .box")
  .delay(2000)
  .turn("right")
  .delay(2000)
  .turn("back")
  .delay(2000)
  .turn("left")
  .delay(2000)
  .turn("top")
  .delay(2000)
  .turn("bottom")
  .delay(2000)
  .turn("front")
```

which could be simplified to:

```
 ["right", "back", "left", "top", "bottom", "front"].reduce(
   (chain, turn) => chain.delay(2000).turn(turn),
   $(".cube .box")
 );
```